# Section number is not getting printed

Tags: sectioning

I am not getting the section numbers. for ex. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.. are not getting printed in output. I want it to be displayed both in table of contents and main page. Right now it is only displayed on table of contents. not on the main page. these are the packages i used. but i am not getting the numbers of sections in the chapters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introductions}

this is a test document.

\section{Hello}

aivbvilbwvuii

\section{bye}

sdvger

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` in the preamble. `1` means `sections`. If subsections are meant as well, use `2`, the deeper the nesting, the higher the number. At the moment, the question is unclear, since no document is provided.

Comment: I have added one image in my question. hope that would be helpful.

Comment: Please don' include code as images! Use copy-and-paste to include it, so we can copy the code ourselves.

Comment: i have added the code. In the output I am getting the section names as Hello and Bye. I want them to be 1.1 Hello. 1.2 Bye.

Comment: @RonakD -- the code you posted gives the result you ask for.  there's something you're not telling ux.

Comment: There was a recent bug in `titlesec` that might have caused this. Make sure your distribution is up to date.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That's most likely the cause of the problem

Comment: @barbara Hello.. I was expecting the result.. but in output I am not getting section numbering.. only section name is getting printed.. as Alan said.. i will try to update my distribution..

Comment: @Alan I checked with the updates of my distribution.. its upto date.. but problems is still there..

Comment: @AlanMunn I uninstalled and installed the distribution again.. so i got the most recent version of distribution.. and problem got solved.. :) Thanks a lot buddy..!! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a new version of a required package.