# Section/subsection numbering doesn't appear on titles on my computer only

Tags: numbering, lyx, titlesec

I am a new LyX user and something strange is happening when I generate on my computer: the section numbering is not appearing on the titles.

I already checked the document settings ToC option and tried to change "manually" the `\secnumdepth 3` LaTeX parameter to `5`.

However, it look like it is specific to my computer (Ubuntu mate Xenial) because, on my friend's Mac, the numbering is working.
The ToC is also working well.

I use the TeX template: thesis-template-latex.tex, the class `dcsbook.cls` with the style `dcslib.sty` from this page:
http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/dcsgroup-classes.html

I suspect one of the Ubuntu LaTeX lib related packages that I installed while starting using LyX to be the origin of the problem.

Does anybody have any clue what the problem is?

[image: section and subsection titles without numbering]

Answer (score 0):

Checking other answers, I finally found it!

It was a bug in titlesec that wasn't uptodate (apparently it not the first time it's happening, the same kind of bug appeared on 2010, [Section number is not getting printed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303494/section-number-is-not-getting-printed) ).

I hope it will help others anyway.